# Can't install Ubuntu 10.04 with 12.04 already installed

Tags: 12.04, boot, grub2, system-installation, 10.04

I have a machine with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Desktop installed and everything works find.  I would like to install 10.04 LTS on a second partition.  I tried booting from a 10.04 DVD through the BIOS.  When the 10.04 disk is in the drive, it is not listed as a bootable device.  Only my linux partition is listed as bootable drive.  The DVD drive is listed as a bootable device with other distributions such as 13.04 and 13.10.  My kernel version is Ubuntu 3.11.0-19.33~precise-generic 3.11.10.5.  My grub version is 1.99-21buntun3.14.

Comment: silly question, but are you sure you are trying to set the boot device from the BIOS, and not from grub? The bios is before grub and has nothing to do with what is installed.

Comment: I would suggest to re-burn the 10.04 image to a DVD, this should solve the issue if the DVD for 10.04 didn't burn correctly. There is no reason you shouldn't be able to boot 10.04 from a DVD. As a side note, do you want to install 10.04 Desktop or Server. 10.04 Desktop has already reached EOL and Server just has about a year of support left. Why would you want to install 10.04?

Comment: @Jacob he mentioned *"I tried booting from a 10.04 DVD through the BIOS"*... Moreover he is able to boot 13.04 and 13.10. So, the OP probably knows that he needs to set boot-priority in his BIOS to be able to boot the DVD...

Comment: @Aditya I thought so, that's why I called it a "silly question", but at the same time, then there is no reason why he cannot boot from the disk (I just tried 10.04 on a 12.04 to make sure). Let's see what happens :).

Comment: This is puzzling indeed as I've been using / burning / installing Linux for a number of years.  When I insert the 10.04 DVD and reboot, I cannot set it (the DVD drive) as the number 1 boot priority in the BIOS.  In fact, I can't select the DVD drive at all.  I can set the the DVD drive as the number 1 boot priority with other distros of linux including 12.04 and 13.10 etc.  It is a good burn. I've tried it on other machines and reburned to.  Yes, I'm fully aware 10.04 LTS is out of support but I still need it for a legacy support project.

Comment: @user265603 That's really bizarre indeed...

Comment: Unfounded suggestion, but what happens if you make a bootable usb and try to boot from that?

Answer (score 1):

Unified Extensible Firmware Interface (UEFI) Boot was enabled in my BIOS.  After disabling it, I could boot from the 10.04 CD / DVD.  Media and burn had no impact.

Comment: But then you were able to boot from 12.04 CD/DVD. Can you expand to explain why was 12.04 able to boot but 10.04 not?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure.  UEFI is the next generation of BIOS.  As I understand, 10.04 may not have sufficient bindings to be detected in the UEFI start up process while 12.04 has sufficient bindings.  There's lots of chatter about 10.04 and UEFI.